# Please vote on whether to make [code] a synonym of [cryptograms]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Another meta question about synonymisation!

Since [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher), [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message), and [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms) are all synonyms, surely [code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) should be as well?

You can vote on it [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cryptograms/synonyms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answering just so that there can *be* an accepted answer...

### [code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) is now a synonym of the others, hence [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).