# Should we merge [cryptograms] and [encoded-message]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Surely [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms) is the same as [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message). Should the [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message) questions be merged into the [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms) tag as cryptograms is the proper name for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms) and [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message) tags [**already count as synonyms**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cryptograms/synonyms).

However, the [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms) and [code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) tags do not. There is an [open proposal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cryptograms/synonyms) to make them synonyms, and cince "code" clearly means the same as "encoded message", and [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) is already a synonym of [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms), it [seems to me](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/please-vote-on-whether-to-make-tagcode-a-synonym-of-tagcryptograms?rq=1) that [code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) should be as well.

Comment: BOOM. SYNONYMIZED.

Comment: @Emrakul Great! :-D How about [status-completed] for this post and the other one I've linked to?

Comment: Your request has been status-completed.